# How to implement loading indicator with Redux in an app with multiple containers without code repetition?

Tags: redux, react-redux, containers, loading, dry

Managed to eliminate the repeating loading indicator state logic from the reducers of multiple container components by implementing a root reducer that handles the loading flags with a naming convention of the actions.

After a bit of refactoring the following piece of code is still repeating through my container components render method:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoading: loadingSelector(state)
});

if (this.props.isLoading) {
  return <LoadingIndicator />;
}
return <ActualComponent />
```

It bothers me to have that kind of code repetition but I couldn't find a way to do it in a centralised manner.

Is there a better pattern to do this or it is normal to have that sort of code repetition in the containers?

Answer (score -1):

1: `dispatch(showLoading(data))` & `store = { isLoading: undefined }`

2: If it's a component like `Card`, default state should be `loading`

Any other case?